# Laravel refresh content after auto scroll looping

Tags: php, laravel, loops, refresh, autoscroll

I want to refresh div content when looping is complete (scroll down and up). Right now im able to looping and refresh page, but the the effect is not smooth. The looping will stop and reset from the begining.

So, can i refresh my page (or if possible only refresh '') everytime 1 full cycle looping is complete?

here's my blade file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css" />

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
    .alert-message {
        color: red;
    }

    .row {
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-right: -5px;
    }

    .columnl {
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .columnr {
        float: left;
        width: 30%;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .row::after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    th,
    td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 16px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .column {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }

    #header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 139px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #right_side {
        height: auto;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    #content {
        height: 460px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .inner {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
    }

    .outer {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h2 style="margin-top: 12px; text-align: center" class="alert alert-info">LANTAI</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="clear: both;margin-top: 18px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columnl">
                    <div class="outer">
                        <div class="inner">
                            @foreach($poli_doctors as $poli_doctor)
                            <br>
                            <h4 class="card-header" style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;color: blue">
                                {{$poli_doctor->nmdokter}} {{$poli_doctor->kddokter}}</h4>
                            <table id="tbl_antrian" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px; text-align:center">ID Number
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($vw_antrians as $vw_antrian)
                                    @if($vw_antrian['kddokter']==$poli_doctor->kddokter)
                                    <tr id="row_{{$vw_antrian['noantri']}}">
                                        <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 20px; width:15%; text-align:center">
                                            {{ $vw_antrian['noantri2'] }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="columnr">
                    <div id="right_side">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Last Scan</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$get_lastvalid->noantri2}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload();
        }, 5000);
    $('#tbl_antrian').DataTable();
    });

    function autoScrollDown(){
        $(".inner").css({top:-$(".outer").outerHeight()}) // jump back
               .animate({top:0},5000,"linear", autoScrollDown); // and animate
    }
    function autoScrollUp(){
        $(".inner").css({top:0}) // jump back
                .animate({top:-$(".outer").outerHeight()},5000,"linear", autoScrollUp)
    }
    // fix hight of outer:
    $('.outer').css({maxHeight: $('.inner').height()});
    // duplicate content of inner:
    $('.inner').html($('.inner').html() + $('.inner').html());
    autoScrollUp();
    // location.reload();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: check this article :
https://www.webslesson.info/2019/02/ajax-jquery-load-more-data-in-laravel.html

Comment: will do,thanks for info